# How to load data into uitable via button in GUIDE MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, matlab-guide

I'm currently creating a GUI using GUIDE (which I am relatively new to). I would like to be able to get the end user to select a .csv file to load into the GUI and for it to be displayed in a table. So far, I am using the following code:

```
function loadBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to loadBtn (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

[filename, pathname]=uigetfile({'*.csv'}, 'Select File');
if isequal(filename,0)
    return
else
    Path=strcat(pathname,filename);
    data=readtable(Path, 'Delimiter', ';');
    set(handles.data_table, 'Data', data);
end
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error using matlab.ui.control.Table/set
While setting the 'Data' property of 'Table':
Data must be a numeric, logical, or cell array
```

I've tried running this same code in a normal script and it works fine, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `readtable` outputs a `table` object. As the error states, `uicontrol.Table` only accepts a `numeric`, `logical`, or `cell` array. Use [`table2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2cell.html).

Comment: @excaza Thank you! Obviously not had enough coffee today :(.